# Difference between $|f|(x)$ and $|f(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570249/simple-explanation-of-uniform-norm-sup-norm) the second answer uses the notation $|f|(x)$ and $|f(x)|$. I am not sure exactly what $|f|(x)$ means, but I know that $|f(x)|$ means all of the absolute values that $f(x)$ takes.

So, what is the difference? Examples are appreciated!

Comment: In his notation, $|f|$ refers to a function whereas $|f(x)|$ (equivalently $|f|(x)$) refers to the value of that function at a specific value of $x$

Comment: what does it exactly mean to "refer to a function" ? I understand how it can refer to the specific value, but not  to a function..

Comment: A function $f$ is different to its value at $x$, which we denote $f(x)$. Formally, a function is the set of ordered pairs in its graph. For example, $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x^2$ for all $x$, is the set of all points of the form $(x, x^2)$ where $x \in \Bbb{R}$. So, it would be fine to say $(2, 4) \in f$, which would mean the same thing as $f(2) = 4$. On the other hand, $f(x)$ is the function value at some $x \in \Bbb{R}$, so $f(x)$ is some (unknown) real number, not a set of points like $f$.

Comment: @user759562 so basically $|f|$ would mean "the absolute value of all the points of $f$"? And $|f(x)|$ is the absolute value of the specific value that $f$ takes at that point $x$?

Comment: It would be the set of points of the form $(x, |f(x)|)$, which is also the graph of a function. I don't know if that's what you mean by "the absolute value of the points in $f$". To answer your original question, $|f(x)|$ and $|f|(x)$ refer to the same number; $|f|$ is just the function that maps $x$ to $|f(x)|$, so we can just denote that number $|f|(x)$.

Comment: @user759562 i see now, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given
$$f:x\to f(x)$$
then
$$|f|:x\to|f(x)|$$
thus
$$|f|(x)=|f(x)|$$
--- rk